# Expanding varargs into corresponding quantity and type in Java

Tags: java, generics, variadic-functions

Consider two vehicles, a Car and a Train. The constructor of the Car receives two arguments and the constructor of the Train receives one argument. The arguments are different in type and in quantity. I'd like to have a generic method that can call both constructors using varargs in Java. Assume I cannot change Vehicle, Car and Train.

The problem is on how to expand `args` in the method `doSomething`. Throwing the variable `args` inside of the new instance of type `M` will not work. Is this doable?

```
public class MainTest {

    // Receive concrete type of vehicle and arguments for its constructor (variable)
    public <M extends Vehicle> M doSomething(Class<M> a, Object... args)
            throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {

        // How to pass variable number of arguments for the constructors?
        M m = a.newInstance(  args  );  // <-- Problem is here, possible to solve?

        return m;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        MainTest test = new MainTest();
        Car c = test.doSomething(Car.class, "Jill", 35);
        Train t = test.doSomething(Train.class, 35.1);
    }
}

public class Vehicle {
    /* currently empty */
}

public class Car extends Vehicle {
    public Car(String name, int n) {
    }
}

public class Train extends Vehicle {
    public Train(double d) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that [the `newInstance` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance--) doesn't take any arguments.  It calls the no-argument constructor if it exists.

To pass arguments to a constructor when you have only the class, you will need to use reflection to find the appropriate constructor.  On the `Class` object, call [the `getConstructors()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructors--) and loop over the returned array of `Constructor` objects to find the appropriate one, or call [the `getConstructor` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor-java.lang.Class...-), passing the `Class` objects representing the types of the parameters to get a specific constructor.  Since there is only one constructor for each class you have listed, just get the first element of the array returned by `getConstructors()`.

When you have the appropriate `Constructor`, call its [`newInstance` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance-java.lang.Object...-), which does take constructor arguments in its parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Crude example...

```
public <M extends Vehicle> M doSomething(Class<M> a, Object... args)
        throws Exception {

    for(Constructor constructor : a.getConstructors()) {
      if(constructor.getParameterTypes().length == args.length) {
          return (M) constructor.newInstance(args);
      }
    }
    throw new Exception("constructor not found");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem could be solve in a more elegant way by using the factory design pattern.

Create an enum:

```
enum VehicleType {CAR, TRAIN;}
```

Then your factory method becomes:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T extends Vehicle> T buildVehicle(VehicleType model, Object... args) {
    switch (model) {
        case CAR:
            return (T) new Car((String) args[0], (int) args[1]);
        case TRAIN:
            return (T) new Train((double) args[0]);
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

And finally the main:

```
Car c = buildVehicle(VehicleType.CAR, "Jill", 35);
Train t = buildVehicle(VehicleType.TRAIN, 35.2);
```

No more need for reflection and nicer code IMO.

Comment: In my case, and like I mentioned in the question, *I cannot change Vehicle, Car and Train*. Still useful for other cases though.

Comment: @Daniel I never changed your classes (literally copy-pasted). You don't need to.

Comment: You're correct, my apologies! I didn't mention it, but I'm using this for a project where I'm passing in dozens of classes and using reflection there's much less code involved. I already selected another answer since I feel it was more to the point of the question, but thanks. (Still upvoted as it was deserved!)